# How do I store the tmp object in a map, to acess the object outside of it's creation context

Tags: c++, pointers

I am relatively new to C++. I tried to break down the problem.

All code is also here:  https://onlinegdb.com/wAmLAONkF (can be executed)

Basically, I have a function where temp objects are created. The objects are pushed to a `std::vector`:

```
vector<Student> GetStudents(int some_params)
{
    vector<Student> students;
    //logic where students are returned 
    Student s1 { "John", 42 };
    Student s2 { "Bill", 12 };
    students.push_back(s1);
    students.push_back(s2);
    
    return students;
}
```

To maintain the objects, they are stored outside in a `std::map`.

The `map` stores each `Student` by pointer in a `vector<Student*>` (it has to be `vector<Student*>`!):

```
map<int, vector<Student*>> m {};
    
{ //start of new context, other class context in another file, map is passed by reference
    int some_params = 5;
    vector<Student> students = GetStudents(some_params);
```

To store them in the map, I copy references into a new `vector`:

```
    vector<Student*> tmpV;
    for(auto & student : students)
        tmpV.push_back( &student);

    //store them in the map
    m.emplace(some_params, tmpV);

}//leave context

//data loss - Students are lost
```

I do know, that the problem is because the pointers to the objects are stored in a local vector. After I leave the context, the pointers do not point somewhere valid.

But how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `vector<Student>` returned by `GetStudents()` needs to be stored in a variable that is in the same scope as (or in a higher scope than) the `std::map` that refers to its `Student`s, eg:

```
map<int, vector<Student*>> m;
vector<Student> students; // <-- move it up here!

{ //start of new context

    int some_params = 5;
    students = GetStudents(some_params); 

    vector<Student*> tmpV;
    for(auto & student : students)
        tmpV.push_back( &student);

    //store them in the map
    m.emplace(some_params, tmpV);

} //leave context

// no data loss - Students are valid!
```

Otherwise, `GetStudents()` will have to return a `vector<Student*>` instead, where each `Student` has been created dynamic via `new`, and then destroyed via `delete` after the `map` is done using them:

```
vector<Student*> GetStudents(int some_params)
{
    vector<Student*> students;
    //logic where students are returned 
    students.push_back(new Student{ "John", 42 });
    students.push_back(new Student{ "Bill", 12 });
    
    return students;
}

...

map<int, vector<Student*>> m;

{ //start of new context

    int some_params = 5;
    vector<Student*> students = GetStudents(some_params); 

    //store them in the map
    m.emplace(some_params, students);

} //leave context

// no data loss - Students are valid!

...

for(auto &entry : m) {
    for (auto *student : entry.second) {
        delete student;
    }
}
```

Ideally, your `map` should store either `vector<Student>` or `vector<unique_ptr<Student>>`, but your requirement  of "*it has to be `vector<Student*>`!*" prevents that.